# Sending Custom field with JMSPaymentCoreBundle and JMSPaymentPaypalBundle

Tags: symfony, paypal

I'm using JMSPaymentCoreBundle with JMSPaymentPaypalBundle and all it works fine. But now I need to send a custom field to Paypal and the IPN message confirmation send me back it later on.

I've tried to add this "custom" field as ExtendedData inside PaymentInstruction but Paypal desn't send me back this custom field. Is there any way to do this? Part of my code when I prepare my PaymentInstruction:

```
$router = $this->get('router');

        $extendedData = new ExtendedData();
        $extendedData->set('return_url',$router->generate('payment_complete', array(
                'id' => $orden->getId(),
        ), true));

        $extendedData->set('cancel_url', $router->generate('payment_cancel', array(
                'id' => $orden->getId(),
        ), true));
        $extendedData->set('default_method', 'payment_paypal');
        $extendedData->set('item_name', $orden->getItemName());
        $extendedData->set('item_number', $orden->getId());
        $extendedData->set('custom', 'customvalue');


        $instruction = new PaymentInstruction((float)$orden->getAmount(), $orden->getCurrency(), 'paypal_express_checkout', $extendedData);
        $ppc = $this->get('payment.plugin_controller');
        $ppc->createPaymentInstruction($instruction);

        $orden->setPaymentInstruction($instruction);
        $em->persist($orden);
        $em->flush();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself:

```
        $extendedData->set('checkout_params',array(
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM' => $orden->getId()));
```

It can be included other parameters as:
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0,
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0,
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0,
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0,
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0,
...